# I'm running a business which sells tickets for others. How do I account for the money I pay out to the clients?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, small-business

I have a small ticketing business. Makes it easy for some local people to sell tickets to small events. this is really not income as 95% of the money I take in I give out to the clients with a small "Service fee removal"

How do I report this on my taxes? I'm a sole proprietor right now.

Comment: You need to consult a professional on this. There are way too many factors for someone on the internet to give you a reasonable answer.

Comment: "this is really not income as 95%..." what about the other 5%?  Seems like that's profit that should be declared on your taxes.

Comment: yeah sorry I mis worded the post. I was wondering if I just don't have to report the 95% as it is pass-through and not income as opposed to the 5% which is income. I know I need to report the 5%.

Comment: Here's a basic rundown of what you can deduct as business expenses. https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/deducting-business-expenses  Legally, the 95% you pay out to the original ticket owners would be tax deductible; BUT I would keep the most pristine records of every transaction and payment ever to avoid problems down the road.

Answer (score 4):

You're charging service fees as a conduit entity for these tickets. While the service fee is not a fixed rate, but a percentage, you would need to record each [purchase at dollar amount](https://www.accountingcoach.com/debits-and-credits/explanation/3).

To illustrate, it would look like:
[image]

Now, to your question:

> How do I report this on my taxes?

You would first start out by filing your [Schedule C](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sc.pdf) from the eyes of the business (the money you earn at your job, and the money you earn as a business are different). Just keep a general journal with the above entry for each sale and close them down to a simple balance sheet and income statement and you should be fine. Of course, read the [instructions for your Schedule C](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040sc.pdf) before you begin.

As always, good luck.

Comment: The schedule C form has one place for gross receipts and one place for the cost of goods sold.